# Iterate through a single tif file in Python that does not fit in memory

Tags: python, tiff

I have been given a TIF file which does not fit in memory. I guess there are some images in it, because I have read that a single TIF file can contain several images. How can I iterate over them without loading it into memory completely? I wanted to find some kind of iterator/pointer but could not find anything useful.

Comment: Can you add your current code?

Comment: If you just want a quick look to see what's in there, you can just **ImageMagick** in the Terminal. To get a list of all the images in there and their sizes, one per line, use `magick identify YOURIMAGE.TIF` If you want to extract image two from it into a JPEG, use `magick YOURIMAGE.TIF[2] extracted.jpg` If you insist on using Python, try searching on SO for `[libvips]`.

Comment: @AhmadAnis there is no current code, since it is more about the approach. It is not possible to open the image directly with a library because it does not fit in memory. I found this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402202/how-to-compress-split-a-tiff-file-4gb-in-order-to-work-with-it-in-python

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the tip, I will try it too

Comment: Try [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#image-sequences) or [tifffile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/375d97f62df6482142b51f1b38a49bdd24d18a60/tifffile/tifffile.py#L444-L448).